# Standard Way for React Import Statements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, import, material-ui

I was wondering if there's a standard way to write import statements in react? For example, I have this:

```
import React, { useState, FormEvent } from 'react';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import {Grid, Checkbox, TextField, FormControlLabel, CssBaseline} from '@material-ui/core';
import LockOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined';
import { LOGIN } from '../../graphql/mutations/login';
import { schema } from '../../helpers/validations/login';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useMutation } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import StatusMessage from '../../helpers/statusMessages/loginMessage';
import Copyright from '../../components/copyright/copyright';
import CustomButton from '../../components/button/button';
import { ExecutionResult } from 'graphql';
import { Wrapper, StyledLink, Form, StyledTypography, StyledBox, StyledContainer} from './styles';
import { store } from '../../store';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import SignInResponse from '../../graphql/responses/login';
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
```

Are there any rules about whether I should import everything from `'@material-ui/core';`separately or together? Does it make a difference apart from reducing the number of lines?

Is there any rule about if I should import other local files/functions after react's own libraries/content? Any other rules/suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are known standard, most of them are opinions rather than must-dos. I would recommend that you take a look at [eslint-plugin-import](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import#style-guide) as it has a extensive list of standards/opinions regarding imports:

> - Ensure all imports appear before other statements ([`first`])
> - Ensure all exports appear after other statements ([`exports-last`])
> - Report repeated import of the same module in multiple places ([`no-duplicates`])
> - Forbid namespace (a.k.a. "wildcard" `*`) imports ([`no-namespace`])
> - Ensure consistent use of file extension within the import path ([`extensions`])
> - Enforce a convention in module import order ([`order`])
> - Enforce a newline after import statements ([`newline-after-import`])
> - Prefer a default export if module exports a single name ([`prefer-default-export`])
> - Limit the maximum number of dependencies a module can have ([`max-dependencies`])
> - Forbid unassigned imports ([`no-unassigned-import`])
> - Forbid named default exports ([`no-named-default`])
> - Forbid default exports ([`no-default-export`])
> - Forbid named exports ([`no-named-export`])
> - Forbid anonymous values as default exports ([`no-anonymous-default-export`])
> - Prefer named exports to be grouped together in a single export declaration ([`group-exports`])
> - Enforce a leading comment with the webpackChunkName for dynamic imports ([`dynamic-import-chunkname`])

**Regarding the order**, what's [recommended](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/order.md) is:

1. node "builtin" modules
2. "external" modules
3. "internal" modules
4. modules from a "parent" directory
5. "sibling" modules from the same or a sibling's directory
6. "index" of the current directory

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about how many lines were used to import modules. I think it's a best practice to first import modules from other vendors, then import local modules. There are some [lint rules](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/sort-imports) to enforce that I think.

Other than that, I'd say only import what is needed:

```
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
```

is better than

```
import * as MaterialUI from '@material-ui/core';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way, just personal preferences.

Personally, I prefer to group imports from a common source, like you did in `'@material-ui/core';`. You could also do that with components, helpers, and similar local modules. Also, I prefer to import first third-party modules and then local modules.

It's all about finding something "logical" and easy to scan to you.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no standard on how you import something. But instead of import everything just import what you need, it'll also help webpack in tree-shaking unused code. So I would suggest this:

```
import { Avatar } from '@material-ui/core';
```

One other I like to do is separate my local imports from the packages imports, it makes the code more readable:

```
import React, { useState, FormEvent } from 'react';
import LockOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined';
import { ExecutionResult } from 'graphql';
import { Avatar, Grid, Checkbox, TextField, FormControlLabel, CssBaseline } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useMutation } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useFormik } from 'formik';

import { LOGIN } from '../../graphql/mutations/login';
import { schema } from '../../helpers/validations/login';
import { store } from '../../store';
import { Wrapper, StyledLink, Form, StyledTypography, StyledBox, StyledContainer } from './styles';
import StatusMessage from '../../helpers/statusMessages/loginMessage';
import Copyright from '../../components/copyright/copyright';
import CustomButton from '../../components/button/button';
import SignInResponse from '../../graphql/responses/login';
```