# Forbidding default exports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, import, export

I recently read that we should not use default exports but I am not sure if I understood it correctly. For example, I am using this:

(1)

```
const PanelHomePage = () => (
  <div>
    <Wrapper>
      <Typography paragraph>
        Here will be the main text
      </Typography>
    </Wrapper>
  </div>
);

export default PanelHomePage;
```

So does it mean I should use (1) instead of (2):

(2)

```
export default function PanelHomePage() {
}
```

or should I not use the word default at all. If this is the case, then how can I export a whole page/function?

Another example:

```
function LoginPage() {
}

export default LoginPage;
```

This works fine but if I remove the default word, it throws an error.

So is this better?

```
export function LoginPage() {}
```

Here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61208572/12541823

Comment: Where did you read that? What was the context?

Comment: There's no difference between both the cases you've mentioned above. I've also heard devs talking about ditching default exports and adopt named exports. What they mean is export without the default keyword

Comment: whether to use default export or not is purely opinion based

Comment: Please see the updated qs @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches are correct and not forbidden. However, it is choice of you or your company which way they prefer. I like separate export default statement since it allows you to export multiple versions of a component, e.g. you can export a simple component and a wrapped version

```js
export const PanelHomePage = () => (
  <div>
    <Wrapper>
      <Typography paragraph>
        Here will be the main text
      </Typography>
    </Wrapper>
  </div>
);


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PanelHomePage);
```